# Using mixins with Ember-cli?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have a mixin `app/mixins/ui-listener.js` which I'm struggling to use with Ember-CLI. I'm trying to use the mixin with the following syntax:

```
import ListenerMixin from './mixins/ui-listener';
export default Ember.Component.extend(ListenerMixin,{
    // class definition
}
```

This fails when I save it, complaining that

> ENOENT, no such file or directory 'tmp/tree_merger-tmp_dest_dir-74tK3rvD.tmp/[app-name]/components/mixins/ui-listener.js'

It seems funny that the "mixins" directory is nested under the "components" directory (as Ember-CLI puts these directories at the same level) but this may just a Brocoli build step. Anyway, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `./` means this directory should be  `../`, you're missing a `.`

Comment: @BasementKeyboardHero this is correct ... I had used the example from the website which apparently should be updated.

Comment: Could you link me to that example

Comment: You'll find it here: [ui-listener](https://gist.github.com/ksnyde/f86e19d0644094e0700c). It covers resize and visibility events at the moment. I'll add scrolling events in the next few days. Eventual goal is to release as a CLI addon.

Comment: I meant the website you pulled it from.

Comment: Oh just realised you were referring to the documentation link ... http://www.ember-cli.com/#using-modules

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't know how do you export your mixin but this should work:

in `mixins/ui-listener.js`:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Mixin.create({
 //some stuff
});
```

in `components/my-component.js`:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import UIListenerMixin from '../mixins/ui-listener';

export default Ember.Component.extend(UIListenerMixin, {
 // some stuff
});
```

Comment: I'll accept your answer as you put it in an answer format but really @BasementKeyboardHero nailed the problem in the comment above .. I was missing the '..' in my reference.

Comment: Aren't mixins created using Ember.Mixin.create(...) and not .extend(...)?

Answer (score 28):

Instead of adding `../` (or even worse `../../../`) into your imports, you can go to your `config/environment.js` and check for the property `modulePrefix`. Let's say the prefix is `app-client`.

Then, you can import by using `import UIListen from 'app-client/mixins/ui-listener';` instead. Absolute works best if you are in a "deep" subroute, etc.

Comment: Thus, importing this way would have fixed your path issue (./ vs ../ problem) and will take care of any other path issues you might run into in the future.

Comment: This is an awesome answer! Doing '/../../../' is a PITA, and then I found this. Thanks!

Comment: Absolutely, using "modulePrefix" definitely helps especially when your application starts going into multiple folders deep.