# Ember isController V/s isRoute V/s isComponent

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I have a common mixin with methods triggered from different places (route/controller/component)

My question is what is the best way to accurately identify the context for 'this' (i.e. whether the call is originating from a route/controller/component)

I have this

```
isRoute: Ember.computed('target', function() {
        const isUndefined = typeof this.get('target') === 'undefined'
        return isUndefined ? true : false
    }),

    isController: Ember.computed('target', function() {
        const isUndefined = typeof this.get('target') === 'undefined'
        return isUndefined ? false : true
    }),
```

However, even for the component, the isController returns true. So it is kind of not uniquely identifying.

I need an accurate way to uniquely identify all 3.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing things that way, I would suggest different mixins for different places and then sharing the common code between the mixins by using another object. Allows you to do what you are after without mixing senate code together.

Answer (score 0):

You can approach like this

../Mixin.js

```
Ember.Mixin.create({
    actions :{

        identifyFromLocation: function(isFromController, isFromRoute, isFromComponent) {
            if (isFromController) {
                //Do Process here if from controller
            }
            if (isFromModel) {
                //Do Process here if from Model
            }
            if (isFromComponent) {
                //Do Process here if from component
            }
        }
    }
});
```

../route.js

```
Ember.Route.extend({
    actions: {
        sendToMixin() : function () {
            this.send('identifyFromLocation', false, true, false)
        }
    }
});
```

../component.js

```
Ember.Component.extend({
    actions: {
        sendToMixin() : function () {
            this.send('identifyFromLocation', false, false, true)
        }
    }
});
```

../controller.js

```
Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions: {
        sendToMixin() : function () {
            this.send('identifyFromLocation', true, false, false)
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Can I ask if the way I was doing isRoute, isController...is that not a safe way of identifying. Any issues you see with that ?

Comment: Also how do I trigger sendToMixin in each of the 3 places ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27375856/using-mixins-with-ember-cli/27378249#27378249

Answer (score 0):

I think a relativly save way to verify if something is a controller is just to use `instanceof`:

```
if(this instanceof Ember.Controller) {...}
```

This should also work for routes & components.

Comment: Thx a lot..so will it also uniquely identify component as well ?